# Как переводить символы в пятнадцатеричную систему счисления?

Tags: pascal

На вход программе подаётся последовательность символов, заканчивающаяся точкой (точка - признак конца и в последовательность не входит). Вывести слово YES, если введённая последовательность является правильной записью чётного числа в пятнадцатеричной системе счисления, NO в противном случае.

Помогите мне, пожалуйста. Как переводить символы в пятнадцатеричную систему счисления, и что такое пятнадцатеричная система счисления?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, пятнадцатеричная система счисления будет содержать символы 0..9, A,B,C,D,E (и, возможно, в нижнем регистре).

То есть, задача сводиться к тому, что нужно читать символы и проверять, входят ли они в множество возможных символов (в паскале это делается очень просто - `if c in ['0'..'9','A'..'E','a'..'e'] then ....`). Если хотя бы один символ не подходит, значит выводить NO.

По ходу чтения нужно переводить в десятичное, чтобы потом на четность проверить. Делается это просто: текущий результат умножается на 15, и добавляется текущая цифра. (Да, в этом случае 'a' будет цифрой со значением 10, 'e' - со значением 14.) Текущий результат в самом начале - 0.

Проверить на четность - это совсем просто. `if a mod 2 = 0 then`

И почитать [это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: На четность проверить можно, посчитав количество нечетных цифр в числе. Если оно четно, то число четное, если не четно, значит нечетное.

1. `15^n` - нечетное. 
3. `15^n*B`, где B нечетное - нечетно (`15^n*A`, где `A` четное - четно, на четность не влияиет).
4. Нечетное + нечетное => четное (`15^n*b+15^k*c`=> четное, только если b и с нечетные или четные одновременно).
5. Если количество нечетных четно - профит.

Т.е. переводить в 10-ю систему смысла нет, учитывая, что ограничения по длине записи в задаче нет.

Comment: Я думал о подобном, но решил, что это будет сложно для @Fortuni. К тому же, возможно, преподаватель не оценит такое решение.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: Только я не понимаю: "По ходу чтения нужно переводить в десятичное, что бы потом на четность проверить. Делается это просто - текущий результат умножается на 15 и добавляется текущая цифра. (да, в этом случае 'a' будет цифрой с значением 10, 'e' - с значением 14.). Текущий результат в самом начале - 0." напишите, пожалуйста как это на примере будет выглядеть.

Comment: Думаю, можно попробовать вариант @Yura Ivanov - и не переводить даже число.
Но если сильно нужно - это просто. В самом простом случае можно написать большой case

    case c:
      '0'..'9': total := total *15 + ord(c) - ord('0');
      'A','a': total := total * 15 + 10;
      ...
    end;

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, total - это будет наше переведенное число в десятичное, изначально оно равно нулю?

Comment: Да. Так оно и есть.

Comment: И этот case я помещаю в цикл While (c<>'.') и выполняю для каждого с?